# Write a function that flips a coin and returns the number of times landed heads?

Tags: javascript, function

Here is what I have so far. It keeps returning 0 no matter how many times I try to "flip" it.

```
**var n = prompt('How many times do you want to flip the coin?')
parseInt(n)
function coinFlip(n){
var numberOfHeads = 0
var numberOfTails = 0
for (a = 0; a === n; a++){
  var flippedCoin = Math.random()
  if (flippedCoin > .5)
    numberOfHeads = 1 + numberOfHeads
  else
  numberOfTails = 1 + numberOfTails
}
  return numberOfHeads**
}
```

console.log(coinFlip(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second section of a `for` loop is the condition that **must be true** for the body of the loop to run.

You have said `a === n` so there are two possibilities:

## The value entered is `0`

`a` starts at `0`, so `a === n`, the loop runs once, then `a` becomes `1` and it no longer matches so the loop exits.

## The value entered is not `0`

Since `a` starts at `0` it **never** matches and the loop is **never** entered.

---

The condition you test against should be while `a < n`.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. That gets it working. But then, say number of times I want to flip is 12 (n =12). Would it flip then only 11 times since a < n? Or could you explain why it would flip 12 times?

Comment: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`. These are the numbers `< 12` which the loop produces until `a` is no longer `< 12`.  And there are 12 numbers because you start counting at `0`. So it will equal 12 loops.

Answer (score 0):

change for statement to  this
for (a = 0; a < n; a++)